# Change WordPress Woocommerce "Proceed to Checkout" Button URL based on total amount of the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the URL of the "Proceed to checkout" button based on the total amount of the cart because I have six different links for corresponding total amount.

Answer (score 0):

check the code below. it gets the cart items count and modifies the url based on count. edit switch statement for desired result. add this to your theme's functions.php

```
function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() {
$checkout_url = '';
$count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
switch ($count){
    case 4:
      $checkout_url   = 'https://stackoverflow.com'; //your url here
        break;

}
 ?>
 <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $checkout_url );?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">
 <?php esc_html_e( 'Secure Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
 </a>
 <?php
}
```